Why does python return a 64bit negative number as very large positive?
Here's the problem. I expect as a result -100. I get from other stackoverflow questions that python is using the 2's complement for negative numbers. How would I convert a string to a 64bit number?
Using Python3 under Windows.
Python 3.10.6 (tags/v3.10.6:9c7b4bd, Aug  1 2022, 21:53:49) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> int('FFFFFFFFFFFFFF9C',16)
18446744073709551516
>>> int('0000000000000064',16)
100


"python is using the 2's complement for negative numbers" - Where did you see that? That's not correct, so I think you must have misunderstood something. For example, Python uses two's complement for inverting an int (~k == -k-1), but not for storing an int.

As stated in the other answers: Python´s integers are unlimited in size, so there is no "signal bit" when converting directly to an integer.
One of the ways of getting a 64bit integer from C is using the bytes built-in class: first to ingest your hex string, and then to convert those to a Python int object, but taking the bit information into account:
a = 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFF9C' 
int.from_bytes(bytes.fromhex(a), "big", signed=True)

This method has the option for Python to take the sign information into account when converting.
Also, note that the intermediate bytes object is arranged in memory in the reverse order of the used by current CPUs - not a problem since byte ordering is a mandatory argument in .from_bytes, but beware if you intend to store those bytes in a binary file for consumption elsewhere.

mandatory only if you use an old Python

I didn´t know it was not mandatory anymore. Anyway, the default being different than the CPU native integers is a bit counterintuitive - (it defaults to ' big'  on a x86 architecture) - so, maybe, adding it explicitly every time is not a bad idea.

Not just "on a x86 architecture" but everywhere.

Your assumption is incorrect. 2's complement means that the Most Significant Bit determines the sign of a number. Python's integers have unlimited range, i.e. an unlimited number of bits, so there is no Most Significant Bit.
See also int.to_bytes(8) to turn a Python number into 8 bytes/64 bits (if possible - you might get an OverflowError)

The earlier answer about Python not having an upper bit is correct, numbers aren't limited to 64 bits.  But if you know your input is 64 bit, there's a workaround:
def convert_to_64_bits(hex_num):
    return (int(hex_num, 16) & 0x7fffffffffffffff) - (int(hex_num, 16) & 0x8000000000000000)

This explicitly separates the 64th bit from the rest of the number and uses it to adjust the result.  The function is easily adjusted to handle other bit sizes.
Actually rather than just say it's easy, I'll just give you a version of the function that takes the number of bits as a parameter.
def convert_hex(hex_num, num_bits=64):
    sign_mask = 1 << (num_bits - 1)
    value_mask = sign_mask - 1
    return (int(hex_num, 16) & value_mask) - (int(hex_num, 16) & sign_mask)


this is nice due to providing a way to make the conversion with an arbitrary number of bits!
